# JBoss - Springboot session cookie config setSecure and setHttpOnly

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jboss, jboss7.x

My group has taken over a bunch of applications. All applications are deployed onto a JBoss EAP 6.4.x server.

One application I'm having trouble with is this Spring boot application and after a ton of digging I found it seems to stem from the onStartup method of the main spring boot app. Here's the method in question.

```
public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {
    container.getSessionCookieConfig().setSecure(true);
    container.getSessionCookieConfig().setHttpOnly(true);
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    ServletRegistration.Dynamic registration = container.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(context));
    registration.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    registration.addMapping("/*"); // required JBOSS EAP 6 / AS 7
    super.onStartup(container);
    container.addListener(new CustomHttpSessionListener());
}
```

So the issue I'm having is if I leave that as it is, build the app, deploy the war file to my local jboss instance it doesn't work once trying to perform an action. I can get to a login screen but when attempting a login upon debugging nothing even hits the application code. It jumps straight into the error handler controller.

Now I eventually just tried commenting out the 3 lines modifying the container / sessionCookieConfig() and it works just fine on my local install at that point. This application is working fine in another environment so I'm assuming there's some JBoss configuration I must be missing for the server around the setSecure/setHttpOnly. Anyone have an idea to point me in the right direction? Been digging through this for a good 15+ hours at this point searching around and trying things.

Comment: If you are really deploying a Spring Boot app why is there even an `onStartup` method? That basically works against Spring Boot...

Comment: The application was written with springboot, I believe they did this to work on it locally only or something? I'm not sure and it somewhat confuses me as well. To deploy out to dev/test/production though the war is packaged via maven.

Comment: Mistakenly hit enter above trying to make a new line:
Also to add, the main reason I am trying to figure this out is the app works on test and production, just not the new dev server we are standing up. This is what I've been trying to figure out for quite a while as to potential environment settings that may be missing. I know the use case is odd but it's somewhat out of my control and there's a ton of applications with just 2-3 configured in this way but they all go out to an existing production JBoss server we can't really see the configuration of where they work just fine